# How to minified Typescript code using grunt.js in my project?

Tags: typescript, gruntjs, angular6

I am working in an Angular6 project. In this project when we make `ng build` - it makes a bundle. But when we make a `ng build --prod` for production build it shows some error.
But we can't solve the error because it shows some error in library.
so, I believe to minified my typescript code by using grunt.

I have tried many of following steps, which doesn't work for me.

1. Install grunt cli in my project- 
   `npm install -g grunt-cli`
2. Create a Gruntfile.js in my project.
3. write code in my gruntfile.js

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {
   grunt.initConfig({

       pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

       typescript: {
         base: {
             src : ["src/app/ts/*.ts"],
                 dest:'src/app/ts/*.ts',
             options: {
                 sourcemap: true,
                 declaration: false
             }
         }
       },
   });
   //load uglify plugin
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

   //create default task
   grunt.registerTask("default", ["uglify"]);

   };
   ```
4. At last, I run this command

   ```
   grunt Running `uglify:build` (uglify) task
   ```
5. And it shows this kind of error

   > grunt
   >
   > Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
   >
   > Aborted due to warnings.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about telling what exact error you get, instead of "some error"?

Comment: Hi james, My exact question is.. how to minified .ts files? can you please help me?